# GraphHighlightStyle with multiple datasets

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to highlight several subgraphs of a graph using the following command:

```
 HighlightGraph[
   GridGraph[{10, 10}], {{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
    2 \[UndirectedEdge] 12}, {4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
     5 \[UndirectedEdge] 15}}, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]
```

It turns out that there is no action of `GraphHighlightStyle` on how my subgraphs look like. Compare with, e.g.,

```
    HighlightGraph[ GridGraph[{10, 10}], 
         {{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2,2 \[UndirectedEdge] 12}}, 
            GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]
```

So what has to be changed so that `GraphHighlightStyle` actually worked on multiple datasets in `HighlightGraph`?

Comment: What kind of output do you want? I get the [result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tR2mH.png) I expect: `HighlightGraph[
   GridGraph[{10, 10}], {{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
     2 \[UndirectedEdge] 12}, {4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
     5 \[UndirectedEdge] 15}}, 
   GraphHighlightStyle -> #] & /@ {Automatic, "Thick", "Dashed"}`

Comment: @ssch Which Mathematica version do you use? All three figures from your command are the same on my Mathematica 9.0.1.0.

Comment: Version 8.0.4 Linux

Comment: It worked in Mathematica 8 for me as well, and does not work any longer in Mathematica 9 (at least for me). So maybe someone can suggest a solution for this.

Comment: If you just want to apply GraphHighlightStyle, you can flatten your data: HighlightGraph[GridGraph[{10, 10}], 
 Flatten@{{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 
    2 \[UndirectedEdge] 12}, {4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
    5 \[UndirectedEdge] 15}}, GraphHighlightStyle -> "Thick"]